# What should an epidemic be called in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, biology

Is there a good Latin word for an epidemic or even a pandemic?
The word *epidemia* is probably easily understood by most, but it doesn't seem to be a classical one.
The adjective *epidemus* is attested but rare.
I imagine the Romans and later Latin-speaking people were familiar enough with contagious diseases to call them something.

The best word I could find was *pestilentia*.
Is this indeed the best choice?
Are there other suitable words, whether better or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, *pestilentia* does seem to describe any contagious disease as well as actual plague, just like Italian *pestilenza*, Spanish *pestilencia*, and Old French *pestilence*. The Romans didn't think twice about pretty much reducing any epidemic to *pestis*, plague. 
Actually I couldn't find any attestation of something like *lebra est pestilentia*, which would close the case, but all the dictionaries I checked agree.

However the Romans did distinguish them. Two more generic terms are [*lues*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=lues) and *tabes*. 
I see the L&S entry for the latter doesn't include this meaning, but [this article by Gigliola Maggiulli](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23971275?seq=1), in its introduction, confirms this: "*pestis* competes with broad terms such as *pestilentia*, *lues*, *tabes*, and the generic *virus* and *morbus*".
 In *De Coniuratione Catilinae*, Sallust compares the stubborness of the conspirators not to reveal their plot, to an epidemic:

> [...] *tanta vis morbi atque uti tabes plerosque civium animos invaserat.*
>
> [...] such was the violence of the disease that, like an epidemic, had infected the minds of the citizens.

---

I was about to make an edit to say that adding an adjective meaning "global" would sufficiently characterise a pandemic, when I saw on Twitter that [just today](https://twitter.com/Pontifex_ln/status/1266995326973472769), Pope Francis wrote ***pestilentia universalis*** for "pandemic".
 Skimming through his tweets, it's interesting to note that in these months, he has always uniquely used *pestilentia*, sometimes coupled with *universalis*, and never the likes of *lues, tabes* or even *epidemia*.

Comment: Strangely, in modern medicine, *lues* has come to be used for syphilis (more precisely, but still not very precisely, *lues venerea*).

Answer (score 8):

I'd use either *pestilentia*, *plaga* or, as you said, an *epidemia*. I'd call a pandemic a *pandemia*, simply because it makes perfect sense and is clear.